# Python - Cross compilation for PowerPC

Tags: python, cross-compiling, endianness

I m trying to cross compile Python-2.7.9 package for my target which is a PowerPC-64 bit, Big Endian machine, but I m getting an error while compiling it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/ac1120/Python-2.7.9_INSTALL/Output//usr/local/lib/python2.7/compileall.py",
line 16, in <module>
    import struct   File "/home/ac1120/Python-2.7.9_INSTALL/Output/usr/local/lib/python2.7/struct.py",
line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import * ImportError: /home/ac1120/Python-2.7.9/build/lib.linux2-powerpc-2.7/_struct.so: ELF
file data encoding not little-endian make: *** [libinstall] Error 1
```

Following are the steps that I followed to compile.
cd /home/ac1120/Python-2.7.9/

```
./configure --host=powerpc-fsl_networking-linux --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --disable-ipv6 --enable-universalsdk --without-gc --with-universal-archs="64-bit"
```

```sh
make install DESTDIR="/home/achauhan/Python-2.7.9CC/Output"
```

Please give me your valuable suggestion to solve this issue.

Comment: If you are building for powerpc (ppc64), why do you specify i686 with `--build=i686-pc-linux-gnu`?